# how to properly use of sed in linux

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I have a folder in present working dir with a file

```
./folder/sample
```

The contents of the file were having some export commands and # lines, how do i get the output removing all those lines, i don't know how to use Sed here its pretty confusing.

content inside the sample file is like this

```
#helloworld

export a=foo
export b=hello

#helloworld2

export c=king
export d=queen
```

the expected output should remove #(commented lines), export words and empty lines, the output should be like this.

```
a=foo
b=hello
c=king
d=queen
```

and also it should rename the file in the same folder on the fly.

```
./folder/rename-sample
```

Please let me know how to achieve this using proper SED command.

Comment: Start by reading the `man` page of [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) and its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html). StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework site, so your question is off-topic here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch seriously i'm confused with sed, otherwise i wouldn't ask this thing.

Comment: So take a few hours to read the appropriate documentation. Then try something, and if you ask a question, give an [MCVE] in it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish your task using this command:

```
sed '/^\(#\|$\)/d;s/^export //' ./folder/sample > ./folder/rename-sample
```

- `/^\(#\|$\)/` matches blank lines and the lines beginning with a `#`,
- `d` deletes matching lines,
- `s/^export //` removes `export` from lines beginning with it.

For further information see [this manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Nit - (your answer is correct), but avoid answering questions beginning with **"Try"** or **"Try this"**. Try implies you are unsure whether what follows will work and are simply asking the other person to be a proverbial guinea pig... Better would be "You can accomplish your task with `sed` alternatively anchoring `'#'` or `'$'` as the begging of the line and deleting the line if found or by removing `"export "` from the beginning of lines using the general substitution form..." Like I said, your answer is correct and well formed, but could be made better.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your suggestion, I'll keep that in my mind.